# Button is not usable when positioned

Tags: html, css, display

I have a button that is housed with a few levels of divs. Whenever I attempt to position the button, it is no longer usable. It becomes disabled. I have attempted to set the z-index to 9999, and that did not work. I also wrapped the button in a div and positioned the div itself, but it still disables the button. I tried with with changing the margins, and floating.

```css
#left_menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 12%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #262626;
  border-right: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
}

#left_menu_top_options {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.left_menu_button {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div id='left_menu' class='lmenu'>
  <div id='left_menu_top_options'>
    <button class="left_menu_button" onclick="changeMenu()">C</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: u r button is working fine what actually u want to do?

Comment: It isn't working for me. have tried multiple browsers

Comment: if that were the case then it has something to do with classes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was causing the issue. As a resolution, I removed the class from the left menu and created an entirely seperate fixed div to use the button in. That worked.